# Return a list of Element by discarding the Sequential Occurrence of Elements

Tags: python

```
i/p 1:
test_list = [1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5,6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 6]
o/p 
[3, 5, 7, 6]
```

Exp: Since (1 1), (4 4 4)  (6 6) (8 8) are in consecutive occurrence so resultant list has no addition of 6 but for last occurrence where  8, 6 are not in multiple consecutive occurrence so 6 is valid
in last iteration

```
i/p 2:
test_list = [1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5,4,6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 6]
o/p
[3, 5,4, 7, 6]
** like wise for 2nd input  4,4,4 is not valid but 5,4 is valid
```

Any suggestion for the expected o/p?
(I am looking for bit elaborated algorithm)

Comment: Does this code work? Do you have any problems with it?  'Is my code good' is off-topic for SO. If you're looking for open-ended feedback, the correct approach would be deleting the question from here and posting on codereview.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JeffUK You probably mean https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that increasing `i` in your `for loop` does not change the value of `i`.
You can check it by runin this code:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    i = 2
```

This code will print `0 1 2 3 4` not `0 2 2 2 2` as you might think.

Going back to your question. I would use `groupby` from `itertools`, but since you specified you don't want to use it, I would do something like this:

```
if test_list[0] != test_list[1]:  # <-- check if first element should belong to result
    res_list.append(test_list[0])  

for i in range(len(test_list[1:-1])):  # Here we use input list, but without first and last element.
    if test_list[i+1] == test_list[i+2] or test_list[i+1] == test_list[i]:
        continue
    else:
        res_list.append(test_list[i+1])

if test_list[-2] != test_list[-1]:  # <-- check if last element should belong to result
    res_list.append(test_list[-1])
```

Comment: thanks for the logic. Appreciate it. And yes, I observed the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group adjacent identical values, then only keep values that have group length of 1.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> test_list = [1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5,6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 6]
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(test_list) if len(list(g)) == 1]
[3, 5, 7, 6]
>>> test_list = [1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5,4,6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 6]
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(test_list) if len(list(g)) == 1]
[3, 5, 4, 7, 6]
```

Comment: thanks for your logic and appreciate your time answering it.